# React router v6 issue: how can I use match.params in element={ } as it replaced component={} How to pass match.params in the element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend

<Route path='/menu/starters/:id'
element={<DetailedCard item={this.state.starters.filter((dish,{match}) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.id))[0]} /> }
/>

Comment: You access it with the _hook_, `useParams`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are "injecting" an `item` prop based on a route match param then I suggest creating a wrapper component to read from the current route and inject the prop.

```
const DetailedCardWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const item = this.state.starters.find((dish) => dish.id === Number(id));

  return <DetailedCard item={item} />;
};

<Route path='/menu/starters/:id' element={<DetailedCardWrapper />} />
```